# Why do we need to write list at front while using map function as split() already returns a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
a = map(int, input().split())
```

not using list infront of map gives me following o/p. Can anyone tell please?

```
<map object at 0x7f28ed8a4fa0>
```

Comment: Of course @khelwood.It should have been map()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function will return a `map` object which is iterable. If you want to convert it into another data structure (`list` here), you need to do it explicitly.

You can iterate map object

```
for item in map(int, input().split()):
    print(item)
```